# Do you know why the autocomplete search is not working properly?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a context where there is a conferences table that stores the conferences. The conference table has a column "city".

I have the code below using jquery autocomplete and laravel so that the user can type for example 2 letters like "co" in the input text and it appears in the input text the results of conferences with name like "co", and if there are cities that also have the name like "co" should appear. But there are two issues:

- first when the user writes for example "co" in the input and there is a conference with the name "conf" it appears in the autocomplete input "conf conf" instead of just "conf".
- and for the cities is not working, if there is a city "Newcastle" and the user writes "Ne" no result appears in the input type text.

Do you know why?

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{

    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->get();

        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['id'=> $value->id, 'value' => $value->name . " " . $value->name];
        }
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/autocomplete-search', 'AutocompleteController@search');
```

jQuery:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
   source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
   minLength: 2,
   select:function(key, value)
   {
       console.log(value);
   }
});
```

Search input:

```
<div class="col col-md-6">
    <h4 class="text-white  text-center font-weight-bold">Search</h4>
    <form class="main-search">
        <input type="text" id="search" class="autocomplete dropdown-toggle" placeholder="Conference, Citiy, Category">
    </form>
</div>
```

For the second issue when the user enters "Ne" it appears the title of conferences that have the citiy as "Newcastle" for example. But what should appear is the city name of cities that have "Ne", for example "Newcastle". Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure how you do it in Laravel, but you basically need to have a conditional `SELECT` that selects the `name` when that's what matches the search, and the `city` when that's what matches the search. What do you want to do if _both_ the name _and_ the city match though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is rather easy to fix:

```
// Change this line
$data[] = ['id'=> $value->id, 'value' => $value->name . " " . $value->name];

// into this
$data[] = ['id'=> $value->id, 'value' => $value->name];
```